# how i can calculate the quantile of a difference of each pair in R using dplyr?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

Let's say i have data frame in R that looks like this :

```
var2 = c(rep("A",3),rep("B",3),rep("C",3),rep("D",3),rep("E",3),rep("F",3),
         rep("H",3),rep("I",3))

y2 = rnorm(24)
data2 = tibble(var2,y2)%>%base::print(n=30);data2
```

i want to calculate the 99% quantile of the difference of each distinct pair in R using dplyr.
Ideally i want to look like this (the third column to contain the values of each correlation pair):

| var1 | var2 | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | B | quantile(A-B,0.99) |
| A | C | quantile(A-C,0.99) |
| A | D | quantile(A-D,0.99) |
| A | E | quantile(A-E,0.99) |
| B | C | quantile(B-C,0.99) |
| B | D | quantile(B-D,0.99) |
| B | E | quantile(B-E,0.99) |
| C | D | quantile(C-D,0.99) |
| C | E | quantile(C-E,0.99) |
| D | E | quantile(D-E,0.99) |

My attempt so far is :

```
data2%>%
  dplyr::mutate(index = sequence(rle(var2)$lengths))%>%
  pivot_wider(index, names_from = "var2", values_from = "y2")%>%
  dplyr::select(-index)
```

resulting to

```
# A tibble: 3 x 8
       A      B       C       D       E      F       H      I
   <dbl>  <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>  <dbl>   <dbl>  <dbl>
1  1.33  -0.539  0.458   1.51    0.990  -1.24   0.306  -0.337
2 -0.542 -0.359  0.0107 -0.0449  0.0222  1.03  -0.238   0.354
3 -0.840  0.843 -1.73   -0.414  -0.874   0.522 -0.0762 -0.777
```

i can continue with

```
data2%>%
  dplyr::mutate(index = sequence(rle(var2)$lengths))%>%
  pivot_wider(index, names_from = "var2", values_from = "y2")%>%
  dplyr::select(-index)%>%
  quantile(,0.99)%>%
  as.data.frame.table(responseName = "QUANTILE")%>%
  dplyr::filter(format(Var1) < format(Var2))
```

But i don't know how to calculate the difference of each pair.
How i can do that in R ?
Any help ?

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do. The quantile of a scalar is that same scalar (e.g. see for A-B `quantile((-1.23) - (-0.983), p = 0.99)` which is just `-1.23 - (-0.983)`. You only have a single value for each combination. So you might as well just calculate all pairwise differences. If you have in fact multiple values per single `var2` entry you should change your sample data to reflect this.

Comment: for each pair combination i want to calculate their difference first and then the quantile of theresulted subtraction.

Comment: If you only have a single value (as you do for the differences), the quantile simply returns that same value. Consider this `x <- 1; y <- 2; diff <- x - y; quantile(diff, 0.99) == diff`. So why use `quantile` if you don't have a vector of values?

Comment: how is that implemented in R ? I just want the code calculation.I understand that you mean about the scalar.I just want the code how can be done in R .

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. You don't need `quantile` here. Just calculate the pairwise differences and you're done.

Comment: How in my code (attempt) i can do that ?

Comment: Do what? Calculate pairwise distances? Can you please take a step back and edit your post to clarify.

Comment: you are complete right.i am sorry i have edited my OR.Thanks and sorry again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an option in base R using `outer`.

```r
vec <- with(data2, setNames(y2, var2)).   # Turn `data.frame` into `vector`
lst <- split(vec, names(vec))             # Split `vector` on names
outer(
    setNames(seq_along(lst), names(lst)), 
    setNames(seq_along(lst), names(lst)),
    FUN = Vectorize(function(i, j) quantile(lst[[i]] - lst[[j]], probs = 0.99)))
#         A         B        C        D          E          F         H         I
#A 0.0000000 1.0022382 3.835410 2.339986 0.94314229 -0.3951486 0.7687369 0.9090856
#B 1.0670568 0.0000000 2.845121 3.407043 0.09522425  0.3434554 0.2499785 1.9761424
#C 2.5396299 2.0461416 0.000000 4.040152 1.37209725  1.4944558 1.8316670 2.6092508
#D 1.2580325 2.2602707 5.075953 0.000000 2.19736422  0.8561844 2.0267693 1.0734799
#E 1.1675326 0.6770104 2.892267 3.324613 0.00000000  0.2610250 0.4595697 1.8937120
#F 1.0451740 1.4040863 4.230558 3.063588 1.34117977  0.0000000 1.1705849 1.6326870
#H 0.8170783 0.2335014 3.068946 3.157065 0.17667867  0.0934769 0.0000000 1.7261639
#I 0.1845526 1.1867908 4.002474 1.430901 1.12388433 -0.2172954 0.9532894 0.0000000
```

This returns a `matrix`; you can convert this to a `data.frame` or `tibble` as needed using `as.data.frame` or `as_tibble`.

Comment: thank you for your answer and i am sorry again for the previous misunderstanding

Answer (score 1):

You can use `combn()` to get pairs of unique var2; in `lapply()` estimate the 99th percentile of difference, and use `bind_rows()` to bind each separate result

```
bind_rows(
  lapply(combn(unique(data2$var2),2, simplify=F), \(x) {
    data2 %>%
      summarize(value = quantile(y2[var2==x[1]] - y2[var2==x[2]], prob=0.99)) %>% 
      mutate(var1=x[1], var2=x[2]) %>% 
      relocate(value, .after=everything())
  })
)
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 28 × 3
   var1  var2  value
   <chr> <chr> <dbl>
 1 A     B     0.339
 2 A     C     1.63 
 3 A     D     2.89 
 4 A     E     1.62 
 5 A     F     1.35 
 6 A     H     1.10 
 7 A     I     0.200
 8 B     C     2.11 
 9 B     D     3.37 
10 B     E     1.30 
# … with 18 more rows
```